# Add java libraries into Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I would like to know if there is any way to embed native java libraries in maven as dependency or something like that but from the internet not from local.

Like java.util or all that jdk provides.

Example of "pom.xml":

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>java.util.arraylist</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of the standard, built-in Java classes are available to your build already - you don't need to add them as dependencies.

If you have a jar (possibly home-built) that you need to use in your maven build as a dependency, you can add it to your local maven repository as an artefact and have your pom.xml depend upon it as normal.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

For more details, see this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955635/how-to-add-local-jar-files-in-maven-project), or this [Maven reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) for details on how to perform this.

Answer (score -1):

Think of Maven as an infrastructure that handles dependencies.

```
mvn install
```

Write to local Maven directory on your machine.

```
mvn deploy
```

Write to an external repository server, e.g. Nexus, so it can be shared with others.  (Your local Maven must be configured to recognize this Nexus.)

See https://maven.apache.org/run.html